# How do I disable auto-redirect to /openmeetings/install after fresh installation of openmeetings 4.0.4?

Tags: openmeetings

I'm trying to automate installation process of openmeetings 4.0.4 for one click ready to login/use openmeetings. For this, I have created one database template including everything which openmeetings asks after first visit to `/openmeetings/install`.

Edited `persistance.xml` to feed in database details and that works nicely.

I'm trying to find out xml/configuration file which contains flag of installation done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untill Openmeetings setup is fully done, it will redirect to `/openmeetings/install` again and again.
There are two ways of complete the configuration setup:

1. Via accessing website itself.
2. using ./admin.sh script on server. You can find more detail of admin.sh here: https://openmeetings.apache.org/CommandLineAdmin.html.